# Entity Framwork: enable-migrations returns Migrations configuration types must extend from 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration'

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I'm learning Entity Framework and specified in VS2012Express .Net45 a class library project.

Add some simple classes and add a class inherited from `DbContext`. Created a console project and run a test program against local SQL Server Express. This works fine.

Updated a class with an additional property.

Tried to enable migration in package manager console like this:

```
Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations 
                  -ContextTypeName EntityFrameworkCodeFirst.Context -force
```

This generates the message:

> The type `'EntityFrameworkCodeFirst.Migrations.Configuration'` does not inherit from `'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration'`. Migrations configuration types must extend from `'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration'`.

Any advice how to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: @marc_s: Thanks for formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it: Took the wrong dll's

Wrong:
Took it by 'Browse to'

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\NuGet Packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\lib\net45

Correct:
Take it from Manage NuGet Packages within VS2012.
Then it works